# Selenium 2 Webdriver + Grid2 + Ruby help needed

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I been playing around with various versions of Selenium, now that Selenium 2 was out I decided to dive into Webdriver and use it with Grid. (tests in Ruby)

My problem is that I can't seem to make that work.

On my Mac I start the Grid hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-staalone-2.3.0.jar -role hub
```

On my Windows 7 I start Webdriver:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.3.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.10.52:4444/grid/register port 5555
```

Then I run a simple Ruby test that just opens Internet Explorer remotely and goes on Google:

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => :ie)
driver.get "http://google.co.uk"  
driver.quit
```

This is run by:

```
ruby wd_test.rb
```

Which gives me a lengthy complaining, I guess this is the most important bit of it:

```
[remote server] org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry(Registry.java):194:in `addNewSessionRequest': cannot find : {platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, browserName=internet explorer, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, takesScreenshot=true, version=} (org.openqa.grid.common.exception.CapabilityNotPresentOnTheGridException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError)
```

I must be missing something very basic. Could someone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem there is no auto discovery for nodes, this fixes it:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.3.0.jar -role webdriver -hub 192.168.10.52:4444/grid/register port 5555 -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=8,platform=WINDOWS
```